# Date read from Database in wrong format?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, formatexception

I'm using `DateTime` in my C# winforms tool, and I'm storing dates into an SQL database using this line:

`iDisc.acquirementDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

The SQL database field is of `DATE` type, and when this date is stored, its stored correctly, such as this: `2013-03-14`

When I want to the value, I use this line:

```
DateTime acquirementDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iDiscRow[TableNames.Discs.acquirementDate].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, a FormatException occurs at the above line, because the string being parsed is not a valid DateTime complaint string.

The value this is being parsed is the this: `3/14/2013 12:00:00 AM`

What I don't understand is, why is the value read as `3/14/2013 12:00:00 AM`, when in the database its stored as `2013-03-14` ?

I'm using `SqlDataReader` to retrieve the data from database. Can post that code here, but I don't think its needed as its very basic.

Comment: Your date may be a of type Date in the database, but you're retrieving it as a DateTime. I don't know that that's the root of your problem, but you may want to look at it.

Comment: No I don't think thats the reason. If I debug the code and look at the values stored in `iDiscRow` (the DataTable Row storing values from the database record pulled from the database), I see the `3/14/2013 12:00:00 AM` value there. So the value is definitely being pulled from the database in this format.

Comment: This is simply the internal format of a `DateTime` object. To convert this to a string in the format you want, use `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` as you did when storing it. Also, since the SQL data type is `DATE`, you don't have to read it in as a string and parse it; you should be able to read it straight into a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `iDiscRow[TableNames.Discs.acquirementDate]` is DateTime already. In that case you just have to cast it.

```
DateTime acquirementDate = (DateTime)iDiscRow[TableNames.Discs.acquirementDate];
```

And reason why you're getting `3/14/2013 12:00:00 AM` is that `DateTime.ToString()` uses current thread culture to trasnform `DateTime` to `string`. Since it's WinForm app, I guess this is your Windows system format for `DateTime`.

Comment: Which line are you referring to when you say I did `DateTime.ToString` ? The thing I don't understand is, suppose I do this from within SQL: `Select AcquirementDate From Discs`, then I get values in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. However if I try the *same* query via C# (using some generic DB functions), the DataTable storing the select's results uses the `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format for the AcquirementDate Column. Till this point, *no* reference to DateTime has been made (in this test case). So why would C# automatically figure out to change the dates to that other format ?

Comment: SQL Server Date column values are converted directly into DateTime objects in C#. What you see 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss' is just human readable string representation of DateTime's value (which is binary). 'mm/dd/yyyy...' is set in your "Regional and language" settings in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The row is retrieved as an object.  The ToString() method is formatting it.  You need to pass the format you want to use to the ToString() method.

Comment: Main problem is that he is parsing object that is already DateTime. He should just cast it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, you seem to already have a DateTime object, no need to format it and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only relevent if it's possible for the database value to be null.  That is frequently my own situation, so I wrote this function in a helper class in a class library.

```
    public DateTime? SetDateTimeValue(DataTable dataTableIn
      , int rowNumber, string fieldName)
    {
        DateTime? returnValue = new DateTime?();
        DateTime tempValue = new DateTime();
        try
        {
         string fieldValueAsString = dataTableIn.Rows[rowNumber][fieldName].ToString();
         result = DateTime.TryParse(fieldValueAsString, out tempValue);
         if (result)
                returnValue = tempValue;
            }
        catch
        {
            returnValue = null;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here is a sample call

```
DataTable data = dataAccess.GetEmergencyVisitDataFromClinicalApplicationSupport(VisitID);

        if (data.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            ValueSetter setterOfValues = new ValueSetter();
            skip a bunch of lines.
            AdmitDecisionDateTime = 
            setterOfValues.SetDateTimeValue(data, 0, "admit_decision_datetime");
```